# paid or paying jobs

Tags: grammar

Could anyone tell me why these two sentences use different verb forms of "pay", i.e. paid professions VS paying jobs?

***Some of the highest paid professions include doctors, lawyers and scientists.***
***Some of the lowest paying jobs are in the hospitality and beauty industries.***

Comment: No particular reason - it's just a stylistic choice whether to use the Past or Continuous participle ***adjectivally*** in the cited context (the choice doesn't affect the meaning *in any way*).

Answer (score 1):

"paying" is the active participle and "paid" is the passive. Both are possible here as we say both

> I pay you for the job
>
> The job pays you

In this way, pay is similar to "ergative" verbs, the subject can be either the job or the person.

So it is possible to say both "a highly paid job" and a "high-paying job".  Note that as a participle I prefer "paid", but as an adjective I prefer "high-paying"

Since the superlative of both the adjective and adverb are "highest", you could say both "highest paid job" and "highest-paying job". Both are correct and mean essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

James K has given you the grammatical explanation.

*In terms of word choice and writing style:*

People in professions are paid a fixed **salary** monthly, regardless of whether or not they work.

People in jobs are or were paid a **wage** weekly according to the hours worked (or piece rate, etc), and if they don't work they don't get paid.

(This ignores contracts of employment, minimum wage legislation, etc.)